# How many strings of letters from $\{A, b, c\}$ where two small letters aren't next to each other.

Tags: combinatorics

I have a string where is only letters $b$, $c$ and $A$ and it has length n. How many strings where b and c is not next to each other or itself exists.

I think that it should be some sum iterating through the count of C in that string.

For $n=1$ it is $3$.

$n=2 -> 5$

$n=3 -> 11$

Comment: Can two $b$s or two $c$s be next to each other?  The title prohibits it, the body is not clear.  We have many questions on binary strings where two $1$s are not allowed adjacent.  Here we have the same situation for lower case letters, then you choose $b$s and $c$s independently.  What have you tried?

Comment: It would help enormously if you worked out an explicit count for the first few small values of $n$, and edited the question to report the results.

Comment: I tried it and for 0xC it is 2 for 1xC it is 2^2 (two places and two choices) but for 3xC it is already pretty long if I am correct it is 6*2^3. I did not manage to see anything in this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that i tried the count of C from the steps of the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $P(n)$ denote the number of such strings of length $n$.

For $n\geq3$, the number of such strings of length $n$ ending with A is $P(n-1)$, since adding A at the end of any such string of length $n-1$ won't introduce bb, bc, cb or cc. Using the same logic, the number of such strings of length $n$ ending with b is the number of such strings of length $n-1$ ending with A, that is, $P(n-2)$. Similarly, the number of such strings of length $n$ ending with c will also be $P(n-2)$. Hence
$$
P(n)=P(n-1)+2P(n-2)\quad(n\geq3)
$$
You can brute force to obtain $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ and now all you have to do is solve the recurrence relation problem.

Comment: Cool, and my suggeste solution with sum can't work? Why?

Comment: @TGar You correctly observed that $P(1)=3$, $P(2)=5$ and $P(3)=11$. For $n=3$ the recurrence relation says $P(3)=P(2)+2P(1)$ and, indeed, we have $11=5+2\cdot3$.

Comment: @Tgar Actually I'm not sure I understood your comment. I don't really know what "sum" you're referring to. This site is full of brilliant people, so if there is a more clever/direct way to get $P(n)$, someone will surely let you know.

Comment: I meant some equation without this trick, just a formula. Actually I think, that the sum 0 to ceil$(n/2)$ $(2^k * C(n-k+1, k) )$ should work.

Comment: @TGar You can find a formula for $P(n)$. The recurrence relation we obtained is one that can be solved exactly by a standard method. You must have been taught this method before you were asked to solve this problem. My answer was only a **hint** because I left to you the solving process which should give you
[$$
P(n)=\frac{1}{3}\left(2^{n+2}-(-1)^n\right)
$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Ba(n)%3Da(n-1)%2B2*a(n-2),+a(1)%3D3,+a(2)%3D5%7D)

Comment: It is 2^n*(4/3)+(-1)^n*(-1/3)?

Comment: @Tgar Yes, it is...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the solution. This probably should work.

$\sum_{l=0}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} 2^l\cdot\binom{n-l+1}{l}$